# Can't get JavaScript result using ajax script

Tags: javascript, php

I am calling php file with ajax script.but when I am trying to call JavaScript in called php file it's not giving me JavaScript result in response. It's give me 
Full script stored in variable.

index.php

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
       //Here i am print response 
      }
    });
```

response.php

```
 $return = $_POST;
   $return["js"] = "<script>test();</script>";

          $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
          echo json_encode($return);
    ?>
    <script>
    function test(){
     return 'Hello';
    }
```

Can any one suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: In order for dynamic `script` elements to work, they must be added to the DOM with `document.createElement('script');`

Comment: Please update your code with complete blocks

Comment: You're also echoing a json string + js code. There's no way js will be able to properly parse that response.

Comment: Hi Magnus I am also getting response but not that script result. It's return full script stored in variable

Comment: Hi Scott Marcus can you please give me further details about your comment or any link relavant to this

Comment: @RaviOza Is `POST` necessary in this case? Since you're already using jQuery you could try using [`.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) which is made for this purpose...

Comment: Hi War10ck, Yes it's necessary.  Because this not my actual code. I was stuck in another  code. And as per that code I need this type of result

Comment: remove dataType: "json", if you want data return as script, html, js etc.